# Website SEO should i use - or |?

Tags: seo, title

I was wondering if I should use (for SEO purposes), either:

```
product_name - product_category | website_name
```

Example:

```
UCleaner - Delete Cache of Computer | HellGates
```

**OR**

```
product_name - product_category - website_name
```

Example:

```
UCleaner - Delete Cache of Computer - HellGates
```

Answer (score 1):

### For Google

Regarding SEO, you can choose first one or second one because Google will rewrite it.

Few weeks ago, Google decided to put [brand name as first keyword](http://www.seroundtable.com/google-brand-title-appending-16432.html) in the title. In your two cases, the title will be like this:

> HellGates: UCleaner - Delete Cache of Computer

### For Bing

Regarding SEO, you can choose first one or second one, no better impact for dash or pipe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any format. nothing change in SEO. search engine take it as plain text. but for visibility purpose normally people like `2nd` example. but it depends on you what you choose.